# How do I fork a child to replace a finished one?

Tags: c, fork, system-calls

I'm writing a program, where I fork n children.
At some point, I send the ID to the parent via pipe, and the parent should respawn that child.

```
int main()
{
    i = 0;
    n = 5;

    pid_t* pids = malloc(n * sizeof(pid_t));

    pid_t child;
    while ((i < n) && (child = fork()) > 0)
    {
        pids[i] = child;
        ++i;
    }

    if (child > 0) //parent
    {
        //I read the ID of a child to be reforked from a pipe 
    }
    else
        if (child == 0) //child
        {
            //Send ID to the pipe
        }
        else //error
        {
        }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to simply refork the child in the parent, with `child = fork()`, but it's clearly not the solution.

**EDIT**

I store the pids in an array, I communicate with a semaphore protected pipe.
If I receive an array number I should replace that dead child with a new one.

I'm trying to post minimal code:

```
    i = 0;
    n = 5;

    pid_t* pids = malloc(n * sizeof(pid_t));

    pid_t child;
    while (i < n)
    {
        child = fork();

        if (child == 0)
        {

        }
        else
            if (child < 0)
            {
                for (;;)
                {
                    //If I finish my work
                    //I send my number in the pids array (0,1,..)
                    return;
                }
                return;
            }

        pids[i] = child;
        ++i;
    }

    for (;;)
    {
        //parent
        //...I read the ID of a child to be reforked from a pipe 
        child = fork(); //pids[?] = ...
        //...
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "refork"?  What is the need for the pipe and sending of pids?  I am trying to figure out what your real goal is.

Comment: Added details to the post.

Comment: What OS? When children die a SIGCHLD signal is sent to the parent and it can react to that. Or simpler yet just waitpid on all your children and refork any that die.

Comment: A 'semaphore protected pipe' seems like overkill. If you are writing small quantities of data (smaller than the size of the pipe buffer), then your writes will be atomic (the kernel will apply a semaphore to the write operation automatically, without need of you doing so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it. Just split your code a little bit more and there it is.

```
pid_t child;
while (i < n)
{
    child = fork();

    if (child == 0)
    {
        child_code();
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (child < 0)
    {
     //error handling
    }
    pids[i] = child; // will be -1 if error occured
    ++i;
}
// parent code
```

Comment: It clearly works, but I still can't find out how to fork a single child to replace a finished one. I added some details if the question is unclear.

Comment: @otisonoza So, tell me if i'm wrong, you try to wait until your child is finished and then fork another one ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to collect your children when they die is with `waitpid`.  The first parameter controls what children you wait upon.  Using a variation of this method you should be able to create replacement children as the current ones die.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>    

void doChildlikeStuff()
{
    pid_t childpid = getpid();

    printf("[child %d]: created\n", childpid);
    sleep(2);
    printf("[child %d]: terminating\n", childpid);
    exit(0);
}

pid_t createChild()
{
   static int MAXCHILDREN = 6; // start contrived code to end pgm on its own

   if (MAXCHILDREN)
       MAXCHILDREN--;
   else
       return(0);              // end contrived code

   pid_t pid = fork();

   if (pid == -1)
   {
      perror("fork");
      exit(1);
   }

   if (pid != 0)
       return (pid);
   else
       doChildlikeStuff();
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int children = 0;
    pid_t pids[3];

   for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
   {
      pids[i] = createChild();
      children++;
   }

   while (children)
   {
      int pid;
      int status;

      if ((pid = waitpid(-1, &status, 0)) == -1)
      {
         perror("waitpid");
         // no more children so end pgm
         break;
      }
      else
      {
          printf("parent reaped child [%d]\n", pid);
          children--;
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
      {
         if (pids[i] == pid)
         {
             pids[i] = createChild();
             children++;
         }
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```